# Using Google Cloud SQL with dev_appserver.py and Laravel (PHP)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel

I am having issues trying to work with a Cloud SQL instance and Laravel. I was able to do local dev work on a Cloud SQL instance with Python but I can't seem to get it with PHP.

Here is the error I get:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/cloudsql/project:instance-db'

Here is my app/config/database.php:

```
<?php

return array(

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => array(

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'unix_socket'      => '/cloudsql/my-project:instance-id',
            'host' => '',
            'database'  => 'my_database',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

    ),

    'migrations' => 'migrations',
);
```

It all works when deployed just not locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to assign an IP address to your Cloud SQL instance and allow your own network to access the instance in the management console.

Assigning an IP address will cost extra.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot connect to CloudSQL from your local machine right now. For testing you should use a local MySQL instance the CloudSQL instance when running in production.

Comment: Thi is just a limitation with the PHP engine on appengine right now correct? I am able to connect to CloudSQL via Python/Django locally, so I thought maybe there was a setting...

Comment: Not a setting unfortunately. There's work happening to open up CloudSQL more formally, we'll be using that once it's available.

Comment: has this changed since?